# Sort posts after filtering them through multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-field, filters, sort

I'm using scribu's [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) to filter posts through multiple taxonomies (which works great!).

However, I'd like to allow people to perform further sorting on the results based on custom fields which have numeric values (eg. `rate_per__private_session` or `rate_per_group`) by clicking on a link.

I thought that something like the following would be all there was to it but clearly it is not.

```
<a href="<?php query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=rate_per_private_session'); ?>">Sort by Rate per Private Session</a> | 
<a href="<?php query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=rate_per_group'); ?>">Sort by Rate per Group</a>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it on my own. The code should be:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'order_by', 'rate_private' ); ?>">Sort by private</a>
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'order_by', 'rate_company' ); ?>">Sort by company</a>
```

Note: I used another plugin, [Custom Query Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-query-fields/), which has "order_by" query var made available.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! I guess that's what my code does, just that I'm doing it without using a plugin and query_args!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript redirect to for passing the appropriate query_params. Checkout WP's default widgets file for the categories dropdown widget. When you select a new category, it automatically refreshes the page and redirects you to the archive for that category. I used this same trick (or code for that matter!) to change the query_posts for sorting using GDStar's query params.

Try this:

```
    <a href='#' id='sort_by_rate_private' value>Sort by Rate per Private Session</a>
    <a href='#' id='sort_by_rate_group'>Sort by Rate per Group</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery('#sort_by_rate_private').click(function(){
     location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?sortby=rate_per_private_session";
} 
jQuery('sort_by_rate_group').click(function(){
     location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?sortby=rate_per_group";
} 
</script>
```

Now get the $_POST['sortby'] value, and check it as follows:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sortby'] && $_POST['sortby']=='rate_per_private_session')
    {
      query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=rate_per_private_session');
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['sortby'] && $_POST['sortby']=='rate_per_group')
    {
      query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=rate_per_group');
    }
    else
    {
      //nothing is set, hence default
      //whatever
    } 
?>
```

Just make sure your url is right. Also check the jQuery(I have written as far as I could remember). Try this and let me know!

Thanks,
Rutwick

Comment: Hi Rutwick. I couldn't get your solution to work but thanks for answering. After much digging, I finally stumbled upon the WP function I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Actually, I may have missed out something in the code, my bad!